# How do I restrict rocksdb memory usage in kafka-streams

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I am using kafka-streams and the off heap memory usage grows up to the physical limits of the machine. However when running kafka-streams in docker memory usage grows past the limits of the container so the container gets OOM killed.

My assumption is that rocksdb is allocating the off heap space. -Xmx can be used to limit the heap usage but I can not find anything similar for the rockdb off heap usage.

How does rocksdb detect the physical memory limit and is there a way to simulate this limit in a container?

Comment: You need to configure RocksDB via `RocksDBConfigSetter` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of memory fragmentation.

You can either tune the glibc memory allocator by setting the environment variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2` or change memory allocator from glibc to jemalloc.

Comment: Can changing the memory allocator be done without a kafka-streams code change?

Comment: Absolutely


Download [https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/releases] and build from source or use a package manager.

To build:
`
./configure --enable-prof
make
sudo make install
`

And set environment variable: LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so

LD_PRELOAD variable lets you override C standard lib functions.

Comment: @asa I switched to jemalloc via LD_PRELOAD, but couldn't measure any improvement over the standard glibc allocator. Is there a way to know which memory allocator is in use?

Comment: Even if `ldd /tmp/librocksdbjni1225549001765976568.so` prints out `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so (0x00007f0bb2126000)` I still don't know whether it's effective and in use.